# Correct Django template url variable to use with the Generic View list_detail

Tags: django, django-urls, django-generic-views

For whatever reason I'm having a tough time figuring out the correct variable to use in my url template tag to properly render my template.

```
#firms/url.py 
from django.views.generic import list_detail

firm_list = {
             'queryset' : Firm.objects.all(),
             'template_name': 'firms/firm_index.html',
}

urlpatterns = patterns("",
(r"^$", list_detail.object_list, firm_list),
)
```

What should my {% url ??? %} variable be to render this firm_index.html template?

Answer (score 1):

if you use the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url) style

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index/$', index_view, name="main-view"),
    ...
)
```

you can give your url a custom name to use to refer to it

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm aware of the url function. For some reason Im obsessed with figuring out the correct variable name when passing tuples.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url), you can clearly mention the name of the view method and in the file.

```
{% url 'path.to.some_view' v1 v2 %}
```

So, for your case, you should be able to do:

```
{% url 'list_detail.object_list' 'firm_list' %}
```